# input numbers to navigate 'audio menus' when using phone tethered to your mac via facetime

Tags: iphone, macos, facetime, call

When using facetime tethered to your iphone in Yosemite (not sure if its different in El Capitan, i havnt upgraded yet) is there a way to be able to key in a number in order to navigate phone options the sort of "press 1 for opening times, press 2 for sales.." sort of thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this one, its very simple, just make sure your on the facetime window and then type the number on your keyboard